# Xcode 6.1 Warning about Launch Image in Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, xcode, asset-catalog

I am using Xcode 6.1 to create a app supporting iOS 6 and later.

.In target's "App Icons and Launch Images", I set the Launch Images Source as "Use Asset Catalog" and  Launch Screen File to "LaunchScreen".

In Images.xcassets which created by Xcode, I fill in every box for "LaunchImage", but there's always a warning message:

> Retina 4-inch Support. Applications using Launch Screen Files and
>   targeting iOS 7.1 and earlier need to also include a Launch Image in
>   an Asset Catalog.

I created another Image Set named as "Default" and fill in the "Retina 4 2x" box with expected image. But the warning message still there.

Any hint to clear this warning? Thanks.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem this morning.  Here's how I fixed it.

1. Select your Target in the project navigator.  Under the *General* tab, you should see the section for **App Icons and Launch Images**.  Where you see Launch Images Source, click 'Use Asset Catalog'.
2. You will then see **Migrate launch images to an asset catalog** dialogue.  Click 'Migrate'.
3. Make sure that your **Launch Images Source** on the previous screen points to the right image set in your asset catalog.  In your case, you would set it to 'Default'.

That should take care of the warning.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me... still seeing the warning, oddly enough.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it for me. Using Xcode 6.1.1 and my project is targeting iOS 7.0.

Comment: I don't understand step 3. After doing step 2 I go to `Images.xcassets` (one click in the project navigator) and I see that below `AppIcon` has appeared a new item: `LaunchImage`. In `AppIcon` I have the same as before (icons generated by `makeappicon.com`, but in the `LaunchImage` section there is everything in blank

Comment: Well, I left that `LaunchImage` section in blank. Apparently doesn't mean anything, because when I run my app in the simulator I do see the LaunchScreen that I previously designed and I also do see the launch icon in the home dashboard.... Got to say I'm loving Xcode, everything is super intuitive (sarcasm)