# Launch Image Xcode 6 iOS 7 warning

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

In my iOS project i have put `iOS 7.1` as `Deployment Target`, but know i have this warning:

```
Applications using Launch Screen Files and targeting iOS 7.1 and earlier need 
to also include a Launch Image in an Asset Catalog.
```

i have add in the `images.xcassets` the `LaunchImage` Folder, and i have add the `Launch Image for the 4-inch screen`, but i still have the warning, how i can do to solve it?

thanks

EDIT: this is the target setting:

[image]

Comment: Have you set the `Launch Images Source` into the target settings?

Comment: i have edited the question, i have to use the asset catalog? but using this the iOS 8 use anyway the LaunchScreen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6.1 Warning about Launch Image in Asset Catalog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881474/xcode-6-1-warning-about-launch-image-in-asset-catalog)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not set the `launch Images Source` so iOS 7 has now idea where to get the images from.

Set this to asset catalog where you have added the launch screens, iOS 8 will use the `Launch Screen File` if both are set.